# Algorithm to merge sorted arrays

Tags: algorithm, sorting

The accurate description is:

The array's length is `n`, composed with key-value pairs. Key and value are both positive integers and the key in each array is unique.

There are `x` arrays, and the keys in each array are not complete identical.

Now I need to merge these `x` arrays by adding the values up with the same key and find out the top `n` pairs by value. If the `n+1`th pair has the same value with the top `n`th pair, ignore it.

If needed, You may assume that each array is sorted by key or value.

e.g. `n=3` and `x=3`:

3 length 3 arrays:`[(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)],[(2,3),(3,2),(4,1)],[(2,2),(5,2),(6,2)]`

merged:`[(1,2),(2,8),(3,6),(4,1),(5,2),(6,2)]`

top 3:`[(2,8),(3,6),(5,2)]`

So what's the best algorithm to do this ?

Comment: `what's the best algorithm to do this ?` the one you create on your own, if it doesn't work, then come back and tell us what in it isn't working

Answer (score 1):

You do a k-way merge by key, and store the output in a priority queue--typically another min-heap.

The arrays are sorted by key, in ascending order. So you create a min-heap and put the first item from each of the arrays on the heap. Then you continually remove the lowest item, accumulating totals of equal items. As each item is removed from the merge heap, you add the next item from the array that the item came from. Output goes on a min-heap of size K, where K is the number of items you want in the output.

The output heap compares values rather than keys.

Quick pseudocode example:

```
heapNode = struct
{
    parray // reference to the input array
    index  // current array index. Start at 0 and increment each time.
}

mergeHeap = new MinHeap
outputHeap = new MinHeap

for each array
    mergeHeap.Add(new heapNode(array, 0)

previousKey = -1
previousValue = 0

while mergeHeap is not empty
{
    node = mergeHeap.RemoveSmallest
    key = node.array[node.index].key
    value = node.array[node.index].value
    // update the array index and put it back on the heap
    node.index = node.index + 1
    if (node.index < node.array.length)
        mergeHeap.Add(node)

    // now accumulate totals
    if (key == previousKey)
    {
        previousValue += value;
    }
    else
    {
        // new key. Output previous one
        if (previousKey != -1)
        {
            if (outputHeap.Count < numberToOutput)
                outputHeap.Add(new outputNode(previousKey, previousValue)
            else if (previousValue > outputHeap.Peek().value)
            {
               // the value is more than the lowest value already on the output heap
               outputHeap.RemoveSmallest
               outputHeap.Add(new outputNode(previousKey, previousValue)
            }
        }
        previousKey = key
        previousValue = value
    }
}

// here you'll have to check the previousKey and previousValue
// to see if they need to go onto the output heap.

// You now have your highest value items on the output heap. Just remove them:
while outputHeap is not empty
    node = outputHeap.RemoveSmallest
    outputNode(node)
```

That's the basic idea. Just need a heap.